# How to run ui testing?

Tags: react-native

I get an error when I start testing the application:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
```

...

```
    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/mmvs/Desktop/ReactNative/node_modules/react-navigation/src/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from '@react-navigation/core';
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add moduleNameMapper in package.json
look at this link : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets